# Creating a function that calculates the Sørensen-Dice coefficient in python

Tags: python, pycharm, typeerror

In my Python class I have to create a function for calculating the Sorensen-Dice coefficient. The Formular is: 2|X ∩ Y|/ |X| + |Y|
Ive been trying for hours but I just can't get it right. This is what I got so far. Might be completely on the wrong path tho, Im a total beginner.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {3, 4, 5, 6}
def dice(a, b):
    _a = set(a)
    _b = set(b)
    return (2*_a.intersection(_b)) / ((_a) + (_b))
dice(a, b)
```

The error I get is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'set'

Thanks!

Comment: The coefficient is `2*|X ∩ Y|/(|X| + |Y|)`, careful about the brackets. Your problem is that `|...|` refers to the size (length) of each set and you didnt consider that in the formula. See @Bharath Radhakrishnans answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very small bug in your code. In the return line, you need to use the size of the sets. The coefficient is about the *size* of the set.

So use `return (2*len(_a.intersection(_b))) / (len(_a) + len(_b))`.

Edit -

How I debugged the code: The error says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'set'`, which is an error about the multiplication operator you are using.

Edit 2 - typos

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiset import Multiset


def tokenizetext(txt):
    ''' convert a phrase into a count of bigram tokens of its words '''
    arr = []
    for wrd in txt.lower().split(' '):
        arr += ([wrd] if len(wrd) == 1 else [wrd[i:i+2]
                for i in range(len(wrd)-1)])
    return Multiset(arr)


def sorenson_dice(text1, text2):
    ''' Sorenson-Dice similarity of Multisets '''
    bc1, bc2 = tokenizetext(text1), tokenizetext(text2)
    return 2 * len(bc1 & bc2) / (len(bc1) + len(bc2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).